# Git could not unlink file during pull - how do I get out of inconsistent state of repository?

Tags: git

While doing "git pull", git aborted the operation since it could not unlink a file it wanted to overwrite, because I forgot to close an application locked these files.

When I close the application and try to reexecute "git pull" and get the following error message:

```
"Error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge: ..."
```

and

```
"Error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by merge: ..."
```

Clearly, git just aborted the pull without doing a roll-back and now thinks the changes that were just pulled are my local changes.

How do I get out of this state? We are talking about a lot of files, and before doing a "git revert" I would have to check manually for each file if there were some local changes from my side.

Note: we are using git in a client-server-like setup, where the distributed developers "pull" and "push&commit" frequently to a central bitbucket repository.

Comment: Hm, somebody answered this question (jan 25th), and now the answer is gone? Was the suggested solution using stash -> pull not feasible?

Comment: What about `git merge --abort`?

Comment: I found an acceptable solution (see my answer below) but are open for better solutions. Also: would you consider this behvaiour of git a bug?

Comment: Is this "the server" you talk about in comments and your answer running directly out of the checked-out worktree you're pulling into here? Reading what you say in comments and your answer doesn't paint the same picture of the situation I get from reading your question, will you clarify what this server's role is here, please?

Comment: @jthill: This is GIT in a client-server-like setup, where bitbucket.org has the role of a server. The developers are the clients and are doing "pull" and "commit&push" regulary.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since none of the above methods worked for me, I used a procedure that does is not fully automatic, but reduces the effort to a few manually selected files (in my case 2 instead of 50).

First stash all files (including untracked and ignored) using

```
git stash save --all
```

Then redo the pull, that previously failed, using

```
git pull
```

Now checkout from the stash to simply overwrite all files, that were changed during the first pull (no merge attempt):

```
git checkout stash -- .
```

Now one problem is left: changes that were made on the server between the failed pull and the second pull are now overwritten. But those should be only a few files (if the time between the two 'pull' was short), and much more easy to identify in the list of working changes you made yourself. Simply "revert" them (I used the Tortoise GIT commit dialog) before doing the final commit.

```
git commit
git stash drop
```

Answer (score 2):

```
git reset --hard
```

will reset all tracked files to their committed state.

```
git clean -df
```

will clean out all remaining untracked, unignored files.

Then you can redo the pull.  Plain merge will do it, you've already done the fetch.

---

I'm fairly sure the behavior's due to a difference in how Windows wants files to work.  In Unix-land, once you've got a file open the directory entry is released. The error you're seeing simply does not happen on Unix system; the open file would become temporary, existing for so long as it remained open to some process.  There's downsides to the Unix way, too, you're seeing a downside of the Windows way. The workaround's easy enough, reset and clean are pretty much your construction site cleanup crew.  It's honorable work, get to know them, they know their stuff.

Comment: But using "git reset --hard" I will loose all my local uncomitted changes, right?

Comment: And git clean will remove all untracked files. If I understand this right, this answer is about the opposite what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: To clarify: it is probably our mistake and a bad habit to do a "git pull" before doing a commit on all our files.

Comment: That's about the size of it. Git's set up for development work in a repo, where changes you care about are being tracked and everything else is detritus or cache.  I still get the feeling I'm missing something but it sounds to me like a separate branch might be the right thing for you here, rather than a stash every time.  Also, have a look at the "--patch" option on add and reset and checkout.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
git reset --merge
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

OR If you are on some other branch

```
git reset --hard origin/your_branch
```

Explanation:

`git fetch` downloads the latest from remote without trying to merge or rebase anything.

Then the `git reset` resets the master branch to what you just fetched. The --hard option changes all the files in your working tree to match the files in origin/master

It's worth noting that it is possible to maintain current local commits by creating a branch from `master` before resetting:

```
git checkout master
git branch new-branch-to-save-current-commits
git fetch --all
git reset --hard origin/master
```

Comment: I tried the first three commands - and my local (uncommited) changes were gone.